# FATAL: [M2Release] Could not close repository , Incorrect username / password supplied

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to do a release with the maven release plugin, but I get the following error every time.

```
FATAL: [M2Release] Could not close repository , Incorrect username / password supplied.

org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageException: Incorrect username / password supplied.
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageClient.createStageExceptionForIOException(StageClient.java:630)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageClient.getDocument(StageClient.java:496)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageClient.getOpenStageIDs(StageClient.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageClient.getOpenStageID(StageClient.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.M2ReleaseBuildWrapper$2.tearDown(M2ReleaseBuildWrapper.java:196)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:882)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect username / password supplied.
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.m2release.nexus.StageClient.getDocument(StageClient.java:485)
    ... 9 more
```

I am not sure why I get this error, the credentials seem to be valid for Nexus when I manually log into Nexus.

When I look in the Staging repository, the artifact looks like it was deployed.

Comment: have you configured the repositoryour in your maven setting  <server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>my_login</username>
    <password>my_password</password>..... ??

Answer (score 1):

I had to uncheck Close repository on the Maven release page in Jenkins, and the issue went away.